# What font is this? (Ubuntu terminal font)

Tags: fonts, font-face

What font is this?

(I saw this at a Ubuntu Linux terminal)

[image]

Comment: It looks like Dejavu sans mono book. But I'm not sure.

Comment: Looks like [Ubuntu Mono](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Ubuntu+Mono), but the font rendering looks horrible.

Comment: looks terrible, though. What's with the baseline of the digits?

Comment: I don't think it is ubuntu-mono. Look at the letter `i` for instance. To me, it is visually closer to *DejaVuSansMono* font.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Ubuntu Mono** from the Ubuntu Font Family ([font.ubuntu.com](http://font.ubuntu.com)) is the default GUI monospace terminal font on Ubuntu 11.10 (Oneiric Ocelot).

**Terminus Font** ([terminus-font.sourceforge.net](http://terminus-font.sourceforge.net)) is the default font on the Linux console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, $ /bin/setfont /usr/share/consolefonts/FOO.psf.gz)

**GNU Unifont** ([unifoundry.com](http://unifoundry.com)) is the default font for the CD bootloader menu, GRUB bootloader, and alternate (text-based) installer where a software framebuffer is in use. (Unifont is full-coverage fall-back font.)

Ref: *[What is the default Debian/Ubuntu console (TTY) font called?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97469)*

Comment: I'm not gonna down-vote or anything, but that is definitely not the ubunto-mono and you are not the only one who makes this mistake. Look at the shape of letter `i` in the screenshot and in the link you have provided.

Comment: The screenshot is likely an alternate text based installer (GNU Unifont). If you look here you will see the i is similar (Unicode 0069): http://unifoundry.com/pub/unifont-6.3.20140214/unifont-6.3.20140214.bmp. Hope that helps.